# Escape from range

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame, range

First I initialize i =0. I'm checking if the user press the correct key. If true, i+=1 and i will go to the other range statement. If false, will print 'false'. However the i will return to the range again and print 'false' continuously until the user press the correct key. I only want to print one time 'false' when the user press wrong key. How to escape the array loop?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7IrA.jpg)jpg)
Here is my code.

```py
for list in range (0,594,6):
    if i == list:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==pygame.K_DOWN: 
                i +=1
                print('true')
        else:
            print('false')
```

Comment: Use `break` to stop a loop. Also please do not post code as images, simply copy/paste the code directly into the question and format it as code.

Comment: Why would you loop for this condition? You can replace the first to lines with ```if i in range(0, 594, 6):```.

Comment: Event handling should not take place in the loop.`event.type` and `event.key` are not changed in the loop. A new event object can only be retrieved with `pygame.event.get()`.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, you're overwriting the built-in type name.

Comment: Not to mention that `list` is a horrible name for a variable holding a number.

Comment: @Barmar *list* is a horrible name for any Python variable ;-)

Answer (score -1):

To avoid continuing the iteration in a loop, you can use the 'break' statement:

```
for list in range(0,594,6):
   if i == list:
      ...
   else:
      print('false')
      break
   other code
```

In this way, when the code will enter in the 'else' condition, 'false' will be printed and the execution will exit from the loop continuing to run the rest of the code ('other code').